# gggenes of a long genome region: is it possible to split it?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genome

I am using gggenome to depict a long region with many genes. I would like to show the region split in several different lines. Does anyone know if it is possible?

This is the way now appear:

```
ggplot(genes, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = molecule, label = gene)) + #, fill = gene
  geom_gene_arrow()
```

[image]

Comment: could you please provide a sample data and expected outcome, the outcome can be shown as data, so as to understand data and expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have your data, but based on the example in the `gggenes` pacakge, try

```
ggplot(genes, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = molecule, label = gene)) +
facet_wrap(~ molecule, scales = "free")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my dataframe genes:

```
molecule    gene    start   end strand  direction   unknown
Seq1    unknown1    1   1158    +   forward Other
Seq1    unknown3    1155    2039    +   forward Other
Seq1    unknown167  2030    2485    +   forward HTJ
Seq1    unknown168  2600    3592    +   forward Uncharacterized
Seq1    unknown169  3769    3599    -   reverse Uncharacterized
Seq1    unknown170  3985    3770    -   reverse Uncharacterized
Seq1    unknown171  4191    3982    -   reverse Uncharacterized
Seq1    unknown18015    4697    4188    -   reverse Uncharacterized
Seq1    unknown172  5230    4694    -   reverse Uncharacterized
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Antonio. Please consider updating your own Question instead of using the Answer section. You can also use `dput(genes)` and paste output in your Question so that people can use the same dataset as you